# How can I use Google documents list APIs with the none-document files such as .jpeg .gif?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-api-python-client

I'm now using gdata-python-client(Google document List API) to access my google drive on Terminal in Linux OS and I have problem to show the image files -- It's just show only the .doc .xls or .pdf files

Is it has some solutions to solve my problem in still using gdata-python-client? I hope there is some solutions better than changing my APIs to Google drive API,that's mean I should restart my project!!. So sad :(

And If I change to use Google Drive APIs.how to do it? or can i reuse my project working compatibility with the new APIs?

Please give me some advice or tutorial.
Thank you very very very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Drive API. We have a Python [command line sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-python) to get you started, and python snippets for every API method including [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list).

Comment: Do google-docs-api(gdata) have some better way to do that,or it can't?

Comment: Documents list API should also perform exactly the same functionality. I am not sure why it doesn't work for you, but since it is deprecated, it is better we support you getting going with the new Drive API.

Comment: I used a method 'DocumentQuery(categories)' that's in gdata.docs.service .Can it use to do my work?